# How to allow redundant nested 'creations' of a disposable asset?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Can somebody suggest a structure/pattern to allow both of the following to work:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        connection.DoThatThing();
    }
}
public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething();
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

What I have in mind is that when `DoSomethingTwice()` is called, only one connection should be created, and should get re-used by both of the `DoSomething` calls (but not disposed by them!).

Edit: I'm going to be using this pattern quite a bit so I'd like to avoid an overloaded DoSomething(connection) and hide the complexity inside the Connect() method.

My best effort will follow as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have a private method that accepts a connection, and then public methods that create the connection and call out to any number of private methods:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}

public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}

private void DoSomething(Connection connection)
{
    connection.DoThatThing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should isolate the action within the `using` to its own method,

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}

public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}

private void DoSomething(IDbConnection connection)
{
    connection.DoThatThing();
}
```

and perhaps, isolating the `using` part as well,

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    UsingConnection(connection => DoSomething(connection));
}

public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    UsingConnection(
        connection => 
        {
            DoSomething(connection);
            DoSomething(connection);
        });
}

private void DoSomething(IDbConnection connection)
{
    connection.DoThatThing();
}

private void UsingConnection(Action<IDbConnection> action)
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        action(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh come on :> UsingConnection is so unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, I'll admit that perhaps in this case... but when you need to do a lot pre-, and post-processing, it can be become quite useful. You add a `try`, 2 `catch` and a `finally` and it becomes a *must*.

Comment: Exposing only the `UsingConnection` method would make it impossible for the client to do some things which would be possible if it managed the connection lifetime, but on the flip side guarantees to the implementation that client code won't do the things it doesn't allow.  This may be important when interfacing with some drivers which include methods to "save context" and "restore context", but require them to be used in LIFO order (if one context is "open", one may open a second, use it, close it, and then resume work on the first, but while the second is open...

Comment: ...the first will be unusable.  If the connections are only exposed via `UsingConnection`, then at least within single-threaded code such a protocol limitation would pose no problem.  If connections simply used `IDisposable`, however, code might try to keep using the first connection while the second was open.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `DoSomething` disposes them, what you are doing should achieve exactly that.

Comment: `DoSomethingTwice` Calls `DoSomething` twice, thus creating two connections, when only one is needed.  It could re-use a connection if refactored.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass `connection` as parameter.

```
public void DoSomething(Connection connection)
{
    connection.DoThatThing();
}
public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    using (var connection = Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: This removes a public method that does something once, and also allows external code to inject their own connection, unlike the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to pass your connection into the `DoSomething` method, like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Connect connection)
{
    connection.DoThatThing();
}

public void DoSomethingTwice()
{
    using (var connection = new Connect())
    {
        DoSomething(connection);
        DoSomething(connection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a Connection:

```
public Connection : IDisposable
{
    public ExpensiveNativeConnection _nativeConnection;
    public void DoThatThing()
    {
        _nativeConnection.Foo();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _nativeConnection.Dispose;
        _nativeConnection = null;
    }
}
public UnDisposableConnectionCopy : Connection 
{

    public override void Dispose(){} // does nothing;

}
```

here's Connect():

```
public Connection Connect()
{
    if (this._connection == null)
    {
        this._connection == new Connection();
        return this._connection;
    }
    else
    {
        //References _connection's ExpensiveNativeConnection but can't dispose it.
        return _connection.MakeUnDisposableConnectionCopy();
    }
}
```

Does this make sense?